# ASP.NET MVC2 controller not recognising authentication ticket

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, forms-authentication

I have a web app that uses custom forms authentication tickets.  I am logging in using a custom authentication mechanism, and creating a custom authentication ticket.

From the web app I then make regular Ajax calls to an MVC2 controller to ask if the user is authenticated.  The controller method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult GetAuthenticationStatus()
        {
            string responseDoc;

            if (HttpContext.User != null
                && HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                responseDoc = "{\"status\":\"authenticated\"}";
            }
            else{
                responseDoc = "{\"status\":\"unauthenticated\"}";
            }

            return new ContentResult { Content = responseDoc, ContentType = "application/json" };

        }
```

The IIS logs show that the authentication ticket cookie is arriving successfully at IIS, but my controller method is returning {\"status\":\"unauthenticated\"} so obviously it seems my controller conditions for checking user authentication are incorrect.

Peculiarly, it all works fine in Chrome.  However, it does not work in mobile Safari.  Can anyone see anything wrong with my controller method?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in this controller action and checking what your custom authentication provider is returning?

Comment: @Lazarus - it only happens in mobile Safari, which I can't run on my dev PC so can't reproduce locally.

Comment: are cookies enabled in this mobile Safari?

Comment: @Darin - yes, and the IIS logs show that the cookies are being delivered to IIS.

Comment: Why can't you run it on your dev PC and access it from mobile Safari? IIS (and attach to process) or IIS Express anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have the answer.  You need to specifically set web.config to force the use of cookies.  My authentication setting in web.config now looks like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" 
             cookieless="UseCookies" 
             />
    </authentication>
```

It is the cookieless="UseCookies" entry that solved the problem.  The default value for this is UseDeviceProfile.  It must have been the case that an iPad does not have a consistent UseDeviceProfile regime.